# SQlite3 efficiency

Tags: sqlite

How does sqlite3 store the records - as text or native data-types.

I changed a column from **DOUBLE** to **INT** and there was no difference in the file size.

I realize sqlite3 uses affinity.

But I'm concerned about storage efficiency - i would think an
INT would take up less space than a DOUBLE.

Also run-time efficiency. if everything is stored as text - then
i assume for a query all the column values would have to be 
converted to a numeric type and then compared - kinda expensive.
(unless it's a key column and then i HOPE it goes stored in a 
numeric type column).

Any help appreciated - as i start the database design.

Answer (score 0):

See the FAQ on the SQLite Official Site

http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q2

Answer (score 0):

SQLite stores values in a [format](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format) that is very similar to the native format.

There are multiple storage formats for integers so that smaller values need less bytes. Floating-point values, however, always use 8 bytes per value.

Please note that floating-point values are stored as integers when possible.

Changing the declared column type does affect the file size because the storage type depends only on the value's type.